# How to view BIM360 Revit file in Forge from generated urn using javascript/Nodejs

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have filtered Revit Files with urn, from the jsTree
['urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:EBacD2IDQ5i2I7s9kAHoIQ',]

**The other comprehensive data is as follows:**

'
createTime: "2021-10-28T08:16:10.0000000Z"
createUserId: "TYBCQWSXD9C9"
createUserName: "Roshan Kerketta"
displayName: "00000000_SCAN_TO_BIM_POWER_SAMPLE.rvt"
extension:
data:
sourceFileName: "00000000_SCAN_TO_BIM_POWER_SAMPLE.rvt"
[[Prototype]]: Object
schema:
href:
"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/items:autodesk.bim360:File-1.0"
[[Prototype]]: Object
type: "items:autodesk.bim360:File"
version: "1.0"
[[Prototype]]: Object
hidden: false
id: "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:EBacD2IDQ5i2I7s9kAHoIQ"
lastModifiedTime: "2021-10-28T08:16:12.0000000Z"
lastModifiedUserId: "TYBCQWSXD9C9"
lastModifiedUserName: "Roshan Kerketta"
reserved: false
type: "items"
[[Prototype]]: Object
'

Is there a way I could view the Revit files in Forge viewer using javascript/Nodejs using the above data

Answer (score 0):

At this step, you have **items** and for each of them you can have multiple **versions** of the "same" file. So now you need to `getVersions` for each file you want to display in the **viewer**.

The endpoint to get **item** **versions** is `GET projects/:project_id/items/:item_id/versions` [Get item version doc](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-versions-GET/).

You can find the **urn** you need for the **viewer** in the response in `data.relationships.derivatives.data.id`

If you are using an example like [Learn Forge ViewHubModels](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels), this function is already included in the backend as it is the final step of the tree before displaying in the **viewer**.